# jQuery toggle class on sub element of li - not working

Tags: html, jquery, css

So I have multiple LI's like below as it's a menu and I am trying to create a drop-down but for some reason, my jQuery code is not working. Can someone help me?

FYI I can't change HTML as it's dynamically generating in Shopify. I can only change jQuery and CSS

```
<li class="grid__item lvl-1 ">
    <a class="site-nav lvl-1 light-body">Furry Artist</a>
    
    <ul class="subLinks inactive">
        
        <li class="lvl-2">
            <a href="/collections/erdbeer-joghurt" class="site-nav lvl-2 light-body">Erdbeer Joghurt</a>
            
        </li>
        
        <li class="lvl-2">
            <a href="/collections/jeson-rc" class="site-nav lvl-2 light-body">Jeson RC</a>
            
        </li>
        
    </ul>
    
</li>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("ul.subLinks").addClass("inactive");
});

$('a.site-nav.lvl-1').click(function() {
  $(this).find("ul.subLinks").toggleClass('active-drop-down');
});
```

```
.inactive {
  display:none;
}

.active-drop-down {
  display:block !important;
}
```

Comment: Your issue is `$(this).find...` - what's `this` in this context?  It's the `a`.  The `a` does not have any children and `.find()` looks in child elements.  Change to `$(this).closest("li").find("ul.subLinks"...`  https://jsfiddle.net/8qucy0h1/ or maybe `$(this).next().toggleClass...`

Comment: Related (but not the issue): you might like to `toggleClass("inactive")` to remove the `display:none` rather than use `!important`.

Comment: Thanks man, it worked. Answer it below I will mark it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is `$(this).find...` in the `a` click handler - at this point, `this` is the `a`.

`.find()` looks at the selectors children - but the menu is not a child of the `a`, it's a sibling.

Change to

```
$(this).closest("li").find("ul.subLinks"...
```

(maybe `$(this).next().toggleClass...` with a caveat on `.this()` that it's always the very next element).

Updated snippet:

```js
$('a.site-nav.lvl-1').click(function() {
  $(this).closest("li").find("ul.subLinks").toggleClass('active-drop-down');
});
```

```css
.inactive {
  display:none;
}

.active-drop-down {
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol>
  <li class="grid__item lvl-1 ">
    <a class="site-nav lvl-1 light-body">Furry Artist</a>
    <ul class="subLinks inactive">
      <li class="lvl-2">
        <a href="/collections/erdbeer-joghurt" class="site-nav lvl-2 light-body">Erdbeer Joghurt</a>
      </li>
      <li class="lvl-2">
        <a href="/collections/jeson-rc" class="site-nav lvl-2 light-body">Jeson RC</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ol>
```